# Need help understanding sorted(x for x in os.listdir(path)) expression

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm setting up a densenet and following a PyTorch-based tutorial. The early part of the code establishes where the tutorial images are saved and looks like this:

```
class_names = sorted(x for x in os.listdir(data_directory)
                     if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory, x)))
num_class = len(class_names)

image_files = [
    [
        os.path.join(data_directory, class_names[i], x)
        for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(data_directory, class_names[i]))
    ]
    for i in range(num_class)
]
num_each = [len(image_files[i]) for i in range(num_class)]

image_files_list = []
image_class = []
for i in range(num_class):
    image_files_list.extend(image_files[i])
    image_class.extend([i] * num_each[i])
num_total = len(image_class)
image_width, image_height = PIL.Image.open(image_files_list[0]).size

print(f"Total image count: {num_total}")
print(f"Image dimensions: {image_width} x {image_height}")
print(f"Label names: {class_names}")
print(f"Label counts: {num_each}")
```

I want to make sure I'm understanding the syntax as I go along:

1. I have a basic grasp of the sorted() function, but I've never seen it used in a (sorted(x for x in os.listdir(path)) way. Can someone explain what "for x in x" accomplishes here?
2. Similarly, when defining image_files, it seems like [i] and x are both used to loop through a range. Is there any meaning behind the different syntax of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is a generator expression inside of the sorted() function, which accepts an iterable. `sorted(x for x in iterable)` itself is the same as `sorted(iterable)`; the only reason its broken apart is because of the `if` statement that is filtering the values of the iterable
2. `i` is the range element (an int), `[i]` is used to index the list;  `x` is a directory. `x` is only in scope within the inner square brackets. `image_files` will be a list of lists with length of the `num_class`

That variable could also be written as

```
image_files = [
    [
        os.path.join(data_directory, c, x)
        for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(data_directory, c))
    ]
    for c in class_names
]
```